# jQuery click function to increase opacity

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm trying to get the div "bio-button" class to both open a div of hidden text and decrease its own opacity. And then when the div of text is closed it returns to its previous state

If you look at [this fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/MGDTech/cU2DD/), the effect I want is the same as when you click on the image.

But I seem to be running into problems with too many functions being called, perhaps. How can I achieve this more efficiently?

jquery:

```
$('.bio-button').on('click', function () {
$(this).parent('img').css({opacity:1});
});
```

This is my html:

```
<div id="" class="team-member">
<div class="team-text">
    <p>hello this is Billy's text</p>
    <div class="close"></div>
</div><!-- .team-text -->
<div class="team-photo">
    <img width="437" height="293" src="http://www.mgrear.com/clients/gls/wp-content/uploads/2013/02/billy.jpg" class="" alt="billy" />                          
    <h2>Billy Senecal</h2>
    <p>Producer / Director</p>
</div><!-- .team-photo -->
<div class="bio-button">BIO</div>   
<div class="clear"></div>
</div><!-- #team-member -->
<div id="" class="team-member">
<div class="team-text">
    <p>THis is Mark's text</p>
    <div class="close"></div>
</div><!-- .team-text -->
<div class="team-photo">
    <img width="439" height="293" src="http://www.mgrear.com/clients/gls/wp-content/uploads/2013/02/mark.jpg" class="" alt="mark" />                            
    <h2>Mark Montalto</h2>
    <p>Editor / Producer</p>
</div><!-- .team-photo -->
<div class="bio-button">BIO</div>   
<div class="clear"></div>
```

Comment: As a proposal for your design. Add css transition to them. Where it works (mozzila, chrome, safari, opera) is makes miracles and where not (older ver of IE) don't affect you at all. For now it just looks to rough.

Comment: Dan, where would I use the transitions? I'm really new to css3.

Comment: Add transition to elements that due to an event change their state - width, opacity, margin, padding, border, transform, font-size nearly anything. You can specify duration and delay for your transition and the property you want to transition or why not all of them.
.class{transition:opacity 1s ease 500ms; -webkit-transition:opacity 1s ease 500ms; -o-transition:opacity 1s ease 500ms; opacity:0; }
.class:hover,.newclass{opacity:1}
Instead of opacity you can say 'all', 1s is the time, 500ms is the delay and ease is your easing type. http://www.w3schools.com/css3/css3_transitions.asp for more.

Comment: Ok, I understand that I can do that. But that would not helping me in this particular case sense I am trying to get one element to do something to another element. Hence the need to use javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
$('.bio-button').on('click', function () {
  $(this).prev('.team-photo').children('img').css({opacity:1});
});
```

To break it down:

When the `.bio-button` is clicked, look at the preceding adjacent sibling that has a class of `team-photo`, then get the `img` element that is a child of that `team-photo` element, then make the specified CSS adjustments to the `img` element.

In the example above, `$(this)` refers to the element that was clicked: `$('.bio-button')`.

Comment: zakang, that solves it! Do you mind telling me why your code selects that image? I took your function and added '$('.bio-button').css({opacity:'0.5'});' at the end to change the button's opacity.

Comment: @MGDTech No prob, I've added an explanation to my answer!